# 2 fancybox links to different boxes - conflict

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, fancybox

I have 2 links that link to Fancyboxes on Ruby on Rails:

link 1's classes are : "why_am_i_here fancybox"
link 2's classes are : "feedback_link fancybox"

When I click on link 1 the first time, it takes me to link 2's fancybox. If I click again, it takes me to the correct link. The other button (link 2) works normally.

Rather than invade you with all sorts of code that may/may not be relevant, tell me what further info you need and I'll provide.

Here is the rendered HTML forr why_am_i_here (link 1):

```
$(function(){
    var search_value;
    $(".why_am_i_here_button, .fancybox").fancybox({
        type : 'iframe',
        autoSize : true,
        afterLoad : function(){
                $(".fancybox-iframe").contents().find(".feedback_link").remove();
                $(".fancybox-iframe").contents().find("#app_header_right").remove();
                $(".fancybox-iframe").contents().find("#feed").remove();
            $(".fancybox-iframe").contents().find("#search_submit").unbind("type"); 
            block_off_default_clicks();
            set_click_listeners();
            $(".fancybox-iframe").contents().find("#search_submit").click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                parent.$.fancybox.close();

            });
        },
        beforeClose : function(){
            search_value = $(".fancybox-iframe").contents().find('#search').val();
        },
        afterClose : function(){
            if (search_value){
                $("#searchbox_holder").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'restaurants/searchbox') %>");
                $("#search").attr("value", search_value);
                $("#user_edit_wrapper").hide();
                $(".search_form").submit();
            }
        }
    }).eq(0).click().stopPropagation();

});
```

This is the rendered HTML for feedback_link (link 2):

```
$(function(){
    $(".feedback_link, .fancybox").fancybox({
        type : 'iframe',
        afterLoad : function(){
            $(".fancybox-iframe").contents().find(".feedback_link").remove();
            $(".fancybox-iframe").contents().find("#feed").remove();
                $(".fancybox-iframe").contents().find("#app_header_right").remove();
            block_off_default_clicks();

            $(".fancybox-iframe").contents().find(".feedback_form").submit(function(e){
                parent.$.fancybox.close();
            });
        }
    }).eq(0).click().stopPropagation();

});
```

HERE is the HTML for each link:

Link 1:

```
<div id = "why_am_i_here_container">
<%= link_to "Here\'s how it works", info_path(:welcome => params[:welcome]), :remote => true, :class => "why_am_i_here_button fancybox rounded-corner", :id => "why_am_i_here" %></div>
```

Link 2:

```
<li class = "app_header_item"><%= link_to 'Feedback (please)', new_feedback_path, :remote => true, :class => "feedback_link fancybox", :id => "feedback_link" %></li>
```

Comment: what really matters is the rendered html as well as the jQuery code you use to initialize fancybox

Comment: @JFK: done! looking forward to it.

Comment: I don't see any html code, just jQuery ... rendered html is something like `<a href="{target}" class="thisclass"...` etc. Anyways, remove `.fancybox` from both `$(".why_am_i_here_button, .fancybox")` and `$(".feedback_link, .fancybox")` ... that should solve your issue.

Comment: Actually tried that already - but what happens is this: I can click on link 1 and get the correct link; but then cannot click on link 2; and vice-versa if I click on link 2 first.

Comment: Also remove `fancybox` from `class =>`

Comment: Yep already did that but faced the same problem. I also tried this after clearing my cache!

Comment: Or change this `$(".why_am_i_here_button, .fancybox")` into this `$(".why_am_i_here_button.fancybox")` ... and change this `$(".feedback_link, .fancybox")` into this `$(".feedback_link.fancybox")` without removing `fancybox` from `class =>` ... is just a matter how you refer to your selectors.

Comment: That still doesn't work but interesting point I noted: I get a 304 response when I load the second link. I think this may be part of the problem - do you have any tips as I delve in?

Comment: In the end I shifted link2 (the feedback_link) to my asset library and removed "e.click.stopPropagation". This meant that link was loaded in the asset pipeline while link1 was loaded when the user loads the info controller. It's not pretty - I'm sure there's a better way - but none of the suggestions fixed the problem like this did. Thanks for the help! It really helped narrow my search for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to track what you are doing moving code back and forth but what I would do is :

Link 1:

```
<div id = "why_am_i_here_container">
<%= link_to "Here\'s how it works", info_path(:welcome => params[:welcome]), :remote => true, :class => "why_am_i_here_button rounded-corner", :id => "why_am_i_here" %>
</div>
```

Link 2

```
<li class = "app_header_item"><%= link_to 'Feedback (please)', new_feedback_path, :remote => true, :class => "feedback_link", :id => "feedback_link" %></li>
```

**notice** that I removed the class `fancybox` from both links.

Then the jQuery code :

```
$(function () {
    var search_value;
    $(".why_am_i_here_button").fancybox({
        // options for why_am_i_here_button
        type: "iframe" // etc
    });
    $(".feedback_link").fancybox({
        // options for feedback_link
        type: "iframe" // etc
    });
}); // ready
```

Both inits are within the same `$(function(){})` ready method. The code above should work.

I am not sure what you are using `.eq(0).click().stopPropagation();` for but remove it for now and test your links.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help up to now. None of these solutions worked. What does work is shifting the functions to my assets folder -but now I can't render 'restaurants/searchbox' because that's not supported in assets. So I'm working on finding a workaround that calls the fancybox listener from the assets folder, but also allows for rendering.